# Setting static ID on an Edge browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, chrome-web-store

The issue I’m facing is an edge case when I have the “key” property set on my manifest file as stated on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/key/ (we’re multiple developers and having this helps a lot, plus we need a static url to whitelist)

I’m able to upload / update the extension to the chrome store without any issue (with the “key” property set) but when I upload to the Edge store I need to build the extension without that key set in the manifest so the upload doesn’t fail.

I just get the following error.

[image]

Thanks.

TLDR: I tried to upload the extension with a manifest file that includes a "key" property set and expected to work the same way it works when I upload to the chrome store based on (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/key/) but fails

Comment: The `key` is ignored by all web stores including Chrome's. All of them calculate the key based on your `pem` file (it's auto-generated by the web store if you don't provide it).

Comment: @wOxxOm you are 50% right, but still missing the last part needed for it to work which it's what's causing the issue on edge. It's obviously not being ignored as after adding it to the manifest we have the same extension ID on every version (dev, prod) and it's making edge complain so.


`Add the code to the manifest.json under the "key" field. This way the extension will use the same ID.`

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/key/#upload_to_dashboard

Comment: In the web store the source of the id is the pem file, not `key`. In the local unpacked extension the source is `key`. You can't force your id in the web store via `key` by design. You can arguably do it by including your personal `pem` file in the zip.